# SSH timeout with long tasks

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I am encountering some problems with the ssh connection to my Raspberry PI. I have it directly connected to the router via Ethernet, and I ssh it from my ArchLinux PC with the usual command, where 192.168.1.49 is the Raspberry PI address: `ssh pi@192.168.1.49`

If I do normal and short tasks, it gets connected and there is no problem at all. But I am having some issues with commands like `apt-get`, `git clone` or `cmake`, where the ssh connection freezes and returns a timeout. When this happens, I can not connect to the Raspberry anymore (actually, it gets disconnected from the router) unless I reboot it.

I thought that the problem could be in the *ServerAliveInterval* or *ClientAliveInterval* values, but I have changed those values in both the Raspberry PI server config file, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and in my PC client config file, `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. I have made those changes following this guide: https://www.simplified.guide/ssh/disable-timeout

These changes did not work, so it is not the problem. I do not know how to debug this and I have no idea where the problem could be.

Answer (score 2):

When this happens, can you still ping your Raspberry PI? Have you tried using `screen` immediately after logging in via SSH? This is generally a good idea to avoid problems with dropped SSH connections.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
No, I can not ping my Raspberry anymore, the Raspberry gets disconnected from my router (it disappears from the web interface of my router). I have read something about screen while looking for a solution to this problem, but I have not tried it yet.
However, the screen solution does not resolve the real problem, but only delete its symptoms, isn't it?
Thank you again :)

Comment: I'm using screen now, but both the problem and its symptoms persist. After the ssh connection with the Raspberry, I do `screen -S rasp` inmediatly, but if the ssh connection drops, I can't detach it, not even do the `C-a + ?` shortcut to view the screen help menu. I am only allowed to do `ENTER` `~` `.` to stop the ssh connection.
Any ideas?
@user193537

Comment: If you aren't able to ping your Raspberry, I guess there's some problem not (directly) related to SSH. It could be that your RPI has some general hardware problem. It could also be that executing apt-get and cmake while having SSH running is too much for your RPI. As encryption might not be relevant for you (if you use it in your LAN only), you could try to install package telnetd which provides a telnet server and try connecting to your RPI using telnet.